# Compressing multiple files to .gz misbehaving

Tags: raspberry-pi, gzip

I had 100 images from a Raspberry Pi project and in order to transfer them to another computer, I used the "Compress" interaction after selecting all of the images and using the right click context menu. The resulting file (.gz) has the correct size, but there is only one image inside (and of correct size), which even after extraction with multiple tools (GUI, 7z, unzip etc) is shown to be a single image of ~300 Mb (which I can open and display).

What is happening here?

[image: An image which shows the conflicting results I get from the GUI and command line]

Comment: There will be one `.gz` per file. Some won't have compressed because they'll have got larger

Comment: I have checked and this is not the case. If I compress it the same way using tar.gz the functionality is as expected.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, I'm afraid to say. Compressing to `.gz` is a 1:1 operation. If you want the equivalent of `zip` you will need to create a `tar` file and then compress that. Let me also change my first comment to read, "_there_ should _be one `.gz` per file, but it looks like your `.gz` is a useless concatentation of all the files_"

Comment: I didn't want any compression, it's already a bunch of jpeg files, I just wanted a way to transfer all the files at once. 
How do I de-concatenate the files is the question?

Comment: Ok, so reading further about the purpose of the .gz format:  "The .gz file was produced by gzip, which is a compression tool. It does not archive multiple files together. It compresses single files." Now I understand the problem, thank you! I misused the format, I thought that .gz and tar.gz are just different compression algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from the misuse of the file format, which is not intended for multiple files, as [roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima) clarified. The gzip manpage states:

> If you wish to create a single archive file with multiple members so
> that members can later be extracted independently, use an archiver
> such as tar or zip. GNU tar supports the -z option to invoke gzip
> transparently. gzip is designed as a complement to tar, not as a
> replacement